# Render JSON to image in Prawn PDF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm using prawn pdf in conjunction with signature-pad gem in my rails 3.2 app and i'm having troubles converting the JSON data to an image to render in the pdf.

I have the signature-pad on completion throw the JSON data into the table and it looks like this.

JSON

```
[{"lx":29,"ly":18,"mx":29,"my":17},{"lx":29,"ly":19,"mx":29,"my":18},{"lx":29,"ly":24,"mx":29,"my":19},{"lx":29,"ly":27,"mx":29,"my":24},{"lx":29,"ly":30,"mx":29,"my":27},{"lx":29,"ly":32,"mx":29,"my":30},{"lx":32,"ly":32,"mx":29,"my":32},{"lx":33,"ly":32,"mx":32,"my":32},{"lx":35,"ly":31,"mx":33,"my":32},{"lx":39,"ly":24,"mx":35,"my":31},{"lx":42,"ly":16,"mx":39,"my":24},{"lx":48,"ly":7,"mx":42,"my":16},{"lx":51,"ly":2,"mx":48,"my":7},{"lx":54,"ly":-3,"mx":51,"my":2},{"lx":58,"ly":2,"mx":58,"my":1},{"lx":59,"ly":9,"mx":58,"my":2},{"lx":60,"ly":18,"mx":59,"my":9},{"lx":60,"ly":27,"mx":60,"my":18},{"lx":60,"ly":38,"mx":60,"my":27},{"lx":55,"ly":45,"mx":60,"my":38},{"lx":49,"ly":51,"mx":55,"my":45},{"lx":45,"ly":54,"mx":49,"my":51},{"lx":39,"ly":57,"mx":45,"my":54},{"lx":35,"ly":51,"mx":35,"my":50},{"lx":43,"ly":45,"mx":35,"my":51},{"lx":54,"ly":39,"mx":43,"my":45},{"lx":70,"ly":32,"mx":54,"my":39},{"lx":81,"ly":28,"mx":70,"my":32},{"lx":96,"ly":25,"mx":81,"my":28},{"lx":111,"ly":23,"mx":96,"my":25},{"lx":119,"ly":23,"mx":111,"my":23},{"lx":126,"ly":23,"mx":119,"my":23},{"lx":129,"ly":23,"mx":126,"my":23},{"lx":130,"ly":23,"mx":129,"my":23},{"lx":128,"ly":24,"mx":130,"my":23},{"lx":117,"ly":25,"mx":128,"my":24},{"lx":105,"ly":27,"mx":117,"my":25},{"lx":96,"ly":29,"mx":105,"my":27},{"lx":89,"ly":30,"mx":96,"my":29},{"lx":85,"ly":30,"mx":89,"my":30},{"lx":84,"ly":31,"mx":85,"my":30},{"lx":87,"ly":32,"mx":84,"my":31},{"lx":101,"ly":36,"mx":87,"my":32},{"lx":118,"ly":39,"mx":101,"my":36},{"lx":136,"ly":42,"mx":118,"my":39},{"lx":151,"ly":43,"mx":136,"my":42},{"lx":165,"ly":43,"mx":151,"my":43},{"lx":171,"ly":40,"mx":165,"my":43},{"lx":175,"ly":37,"mx":171,"my":40},{"lx":177,"ly":34,"mx":175,"my":37},{"lx":178,"ly":32,"mx":177,"my":34},{"lx":178,"ly":31,"mx":178,"my":32}]
```

I have seen [this](https://gist.github.com/branch14/4258871), but i'm not sure how best to implement it?

Controller

```
  def show
    @form = Form.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
          pdf = FormPdf.new(@form)
          send_data pdf.render, filename: "form - #{@form.title}", type: "application/pdf", disposition: "inline"
      end
    end
  end
```

Prawn PDF

```
# encoding: utf-8
class FormPdf < Prawn::Document

  def initialize(form)
    super()
    @form = form
    all
  end

  def all
    text "Form text here"
    move_down 20
    signature_data = [[@form.signature, "Signature of person"]]
      table(signature_data, position: :center) do 
      cells.style(:border_width => 0)
    end
  end
```

Comment: You have a typo on `FormPDF#initialize`: should be `@form = form`. Also, I suggest to use a filename without spaces that includes the extension. Hope that helps

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please see: https://github.com/nqngo/rails-signature-pad-prawns-demo

The signature in question image:

[image: SignaturePad Signature]

Luckily I did something similar at my workplace, so I will walk you through the whole thought process. Assume we store the data in `@sig` and setup a signature box `dimension` :

```
signature = '[{"lx":29,"ly":18,"mx":29,"my":17},{"lx":29,"ly":19,"mx":29,"my":18},{"lx":29,"ly":24,"mx":29,"my":19},{"lx":29,"ly":27,"mx":29,"my":24},{"lx":29,"ly":30,"mx":29,"my":27},{"lx":29,"ly":32,"mx":29,"my":30},{"lx":32,"ly":32,"mx":29,"my":32},{"lx":33,"ly":32,"mx":32,"my":32},{"lx":35,"ly":31,"mx":33,"my":32},{"lx":39,"ly":24,"mx":35,"my":31},{"lx":42,"ly":16,"mx":39,"my":24},{"lx":48,"ly":7,"mx":42,"my":16},{"lx":51,"ly":2,"mx":48,"my":7},{"lx":54,"ly":-3,"mx":51,"my":2},{"lx":58,"ly":2,"mx":58,"my":1},{"lx":59,"ly":9,"mx":58,"my":2},{"lx":60,"ly":18,"mx":59,"my":9},{"lx":60,"ly":27,"mx":60,"my":18},{"lx":60,"ly":38,"mx":60,"my":27},{"lx":55,"ly":45,"mx":60,"my":38},{"lx":49,"ly":51,"mx":55,"my":45},{"lx":45,"ly":54,"mx":49,"my":51},{"lx":39,"ly":57,"mx":45,"my":54},{"lx":35,"ly":51,"mx":35,"my":50},{"lx":43,"ly":45,"mx":35,"my":51},{"lx":54,"ly":39,"mx":43,"my":45},{"lx":70,"ly":32,"mx":54,"my":39},{"lx":81,"ly":28,"mx":70,"my":32},{"lx":96,"ly":25,"mx":81,"my":28},{"lx":111,"ly":23,"mx":96,"my":25},{"lx":119,"ly":23,"mx":111,"my":23},{"lx":126,"ly":23,"mx":119,"my":23},{"lx":129,"ly":23,"mx":126,"my":23},{"lx":130,"ly":23,"mx":129,"my":23},{"lx":128,"ly":24,"mx":130,"my":23},{"lx":117,"ly":25,"mx":128,"my":24},{"lx":105,"ly":27,"mx":117,"my":25},{"lx":96,"ly":29,"mx":105,"my":27},{"lx":89,"ly":30,"mx":96,"my":29},{"lx":85,"ly":30,"mx":89,"my":30},{"lx":84,"ly":31,"mx":85,"my":30},{"lx":87,"ly":32,"mx":84,"my":31},{"lx":101,"ly":36,"mx":87,"my":32},{"lx":118,"ly":39,"mx":101,"my":36},{"lx":136,"ly":42,"mx":118,"my":39},{"lx":151,"ly":43,"mx":136,"my":42},{"lx":165,"ly":43,"mx":151,"my":43},{"lx":171,"ly":40,"mx":165,"my":43},{"lx":175,"ly":37,"mx":171,"my":40},{"lx":177,"ly":34,"mx":175,"my":37},{"lx":178,"ly":32,"mx":177,"my":34},{"lx":178,"ly":31,"mx":178,"my":32}]'
@sig = JSON.parse signature
sigpad_height = 55
sigpad_width = 198
```

You then create a `bounding_box` at the `cursor` point and draw the `line` from the JSON data. The reason why we have to use a `bounding_box` is to set the coordinate of the `line` origin. Otherwise, the `line` function will use the bottom left of the page as the origin point:

```
bounding_box([0, cursor], width: sigpad_width, height: sigpad_height) do
  stroke_bounds
  @sig.each do |e|
    stroke { line [e["lx"], e["ly"]],
                  [e["mx"], e["my"]] }
  end
end
```

The resulting PDF will be:

[image: PDF 1]

Notice how the image is upside down, this is due to the different point of axis-direction between `PDF` and `canvas`. In `PDF` the origin point is bottom-left, where in `canvas`, the origin point is top-left. What we need to do is convert the coordinate from `canvas` style to `PDF` style. A basic transformation is to flip it over the x-axis, and translate it back by `sigpad_height`. The `line` code is now:

```
    stroke { line [e["lx"], sigpad_height - e["ly"]],
                  [e["mx"], sigpad_height - e["my"]] }
```

The end result will be:

[image: PDF 2]

If you do not want the border around the `bounding_box` removes the `stroke_bounds`. A couple of gotchas you need to be careful about:

- SignaturePad captures data coordinates outside the HTML signature pad dimension, hence why you see the rendered PDF signature have overdrawn lines outside its `bounding_box`.
- The above transformation assumes the signature height of the bounding box and the HTML pad is the same. If different, you will need to add some offset to translate the signature back into the correct position due to the flipping over the x-axis.
- Depends on how you store your JSON in the database. You might be able to access the coordinate as a `:hash`. Hence `e["lx"]` will yield `nil`, you must use `e[:lx]` instead.

Comment: Genius! Thank you very muchly.